# Vote to reopen question regarding connected and total domination on the queen's graph

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Note: Now reopened!]

The question concerns the limit as $n\to\infty$ of $\gamma_t(Q_n)/n$.  It is known to be between $\frac{4}{7}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$.

As connected and total domination the queen's graph have been studied together by Hedetniemi and Ameridabi in 2005, I mentioned my new formation of queens which provides connected and total dominating sets for  $n$ is divisible by $6$.  This formation provides the best known upper bound for $n$ divisible by $6$ and $n$ sufficiently large.  Thus, the newer formation was used as an example along with my mentioning of Welsch's formation.

This is publishable material I feel that I've chosen to share.  However, as I'm no longer an academic, I prefer mathoverflow for recreational questions like these.

Please take a look and consider it!

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167839/is-there-a-formation-of-queens-on-n-times-n-board-that-shows-the-limit-as-n-t

Comment: The edited question does seem quite reasonable to me.  I found the original question difficult to follow, and had voted to close.  I have now voted to reopen.